# passing JavaScript variable in clickable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, dom

I want to add part of the current url to the next page(link click).
So basically, I take the url after '?' and attach it to the end of a link.
How can I use finalurl as the link?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var codes = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
      var finalurl = "www.google.com/" + codes;
    </script>

    <p><a href="finalurl">ChangedNextUrl</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/t7wfLt47/

Answer (score 2):

You can use it by invoking a *javascript* method from `a`

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
function goToFinalURL()
{
   var codes = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
   console.log(codes);
   var finalurl = "https://www.google.com/" + codes;
   window.location.href = finalurl;
}
</script>

<p><a href="javascript:goToFinalURL()">ChangedNextUrl</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ID into your `a` and use **jQuery** or **JavaScript** for put inside it.

```js
var codes = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
var finalurl = "www.google.com/" + codes;
document.getElementById("finalUrl").href = finalurl;
```

```html
<p><a id="finalUrl" href="finalurl">ChangedNextUrl</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the code to become like this:

```js
var codes = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
var finalurl = "https://www.google.com/" + codes;
a = document.querySelector('a');
a.setAttribute("href",finalurl );
```

```html
<p><a href="">ChangedNextUrl</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery

```js
$("#id").click(function(){
  var myVar = "addme";
  var href = window.location.href+myVar;
  window.location.href = href;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="finalurl" id="id">ChangedNextUrl</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with one more solution

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  var codes = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
  var finalurl = "www.google.com/" + codes;
  window.location.href = finalurl;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="">ChangedNextUrl</a></p>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based ON URL You need to change / to ?. it will work. or else provide your url.

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
function final_url() {

  var codes = window.location.href.split('/')[2];
  var finalurl = "www.google.com/" + codes;
  window.location.href = finalurl; 
}
</script>

<p><a href"#" onclick="final_url()">ChangedNextUrl</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have done this by using jquery i hope u will find it helpfull**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var codes = window.location.href;
            codes= codes.substr(codes.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            var finalurl = "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46769492/" + codes;
            $('#links').attr('href', finalurl);
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="links" href="https://www.google.co.in/">ChangedNextUrl</a>
</body>
</html>
```